# Retrieve Row based on another row value in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table-1 with structure as below:

```
id  id2 Status
1    1   10
2    1   20
3    2   10
```

Suppose if I don't have an entry for status = 20 in this table for particular id2, then I should query another table with id2 value which is having Status = 10. And if an entry for status = 20 is present in the table, then I shouldn't query any of the table.
Is it possible to do this in a single SQL statement instead of using PLSQL block?

---

`Select * from table_1 where id2 = 1;` 
This will give the result as

```
1 1 10 
1 2 20
```

Since 20 is present in this Query, we should use the id2 = 1 with status 10 for querying the table TABLE_2.

```
select * from table_1 where id2=2;
```

As this query will not have a row with status 20, no row should be fetched. i.e we need to query TABLE_2 with id2 which is having Status as 10.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: Requirements like these are often hard to describe in words.  That's one reason for SO's recommendation on using a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve : Include example data and example results that are sufficient to Demonstrate all the requirements you have.

Comment: Sounds like `RIGHT JOIN` with `IS NULL`

Comment: Select * from table_1 where id2 = 1;
This will give the result as

Comment: Select * from table_1 where id2 = 1;
This will give the result as
1   1   10
1    2   20
Since 20 is present in this Query, we should use the id2 = 1 with status 10 for querying the table TABLE_2.

select * from table_1 where id2=2;
As this query will not have a row with status 20, no row should be fetched.
i.e we need to query TABLE_2 with id2 which is having Status as 10.

Comment: **DO NOT** put your clarifications in comments.  Use [Edit] and improve your question.

Comment: Don't add comments, edit your question.  Also read the link I gave you.